# How to force my jQuery code to run on the list's items, when doing paging or doing partial refresh inside my list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, jquery, list-view

I am working on a sharepoint online team site collection. and i have a discussion board list. now inside the `AllItems.aspx` view, i added the following script:-

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
$('a[href*="mydiscussionboard"]').attr('target', '_blank');
}, 3000);

</script>
```

the purpose of the script is that whenever a user clicks on a discussion board item, the item should open in a new tab instead of opening it on the current tab. this will ease reading multiple items. 
and i had to define my script inside a counter otherwise the script will not work. seems the 3 seconds can ensure that the page is fully loaded.
Now the script might not be the best thing to do !! but at-least it worked well, even when i embed the allitems view inside my modern page, the script worked.

But the only issue i am facing is that if the users do a paging on the items, or click on the load icon, or click on one of the tabs (such as "my discussions" or "what's hot") as follow:-

[image]

then the items' links will not open in new tabs.. so my question is how i can force my script to run after doing paging or partial updates??

Comment: Use event listeners to tell when the items are loaded instead of using timeout.  You can also listen for when the list is paged, tabbed or refreshed.  And lastly, I would avoid dictating browser behaviour for your users.

Comment: @wjervis thanks for your reply.. but can i know exactly  why u mentioned this `I would avoid dictating browser behaviour for your users` ?? now in my case i want to add the list view inside my modern page using the embed web part and using `IsDlg=1`. and if i do not modify the default behavioure when users click on the list items, then on the normal scenario, when a user click on the item link inside the embed web part, the whole page will be shown inside the web part without ` `IsDlg=1`.`. so i want to force the item to open in a separate tab..

Comment: I personally dislike when a link opens in a new tab, since I already know how to make a link open in a new tab.  `target=_blank` forces people to open in a new tab, regardless if they wanted to or not.  Anyhow, let's see if I got this straight.  You have a modern page with embed web part.  This web part contains another page that has the list view that you are affecting.  When they click a link in that list view, it opens within the embed web part. Is that correct?

Comment: @wjervis yes exactly. now when i embed the list view page inside my modern page, i added the following `IsDlg=1` to my iframe url.. this will remove the unwanted components from the embedded page .. but if the user click on an item inside the embedded page, a new page will open within the embed web part, but the new page will not have `IsDlg=1` , so all the page's components such as header, left side navigation will be shown inside the embed web part, which looks totally wrong..so i want the item to open in new tab...

Answer (score 2):

Two things, to avoid the three second delay, use one of the several techniques to ensure your code runs after the page is fully loaded.

One technique: Wrap your code in a function and then add the function name to an array of functions that SharePoint will call after loading the page.

```
function MyFunction() { doSomeWork... }
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyFunction");
```

As far as your code not running after paging, by default, pages are loaded as asynchronous partial page loads. Try disabling the Minimal Download site feature.

Comment: `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push` worked well, so i removed the 3 seconds deploy. thanks for this..now regarding the partial load, i do not want to disable the Minimal Download site feature.. as it improves the users' interactions.. but i want to find a way to force my scrip to keep running after doing a partial load..